# Django template filter to convert a string into single item list

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a template filter that converts a string into a list with just one item.
I did see make_list but that creates a list of individual characters of the string.

Illustration:  `{{ "string"|filter }}` gives `["string"]`

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't. But, you can create a custom one if you wish to do it. Ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a builtin template filter for this. You can write your own according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/). I don't understand the aim very well but you can always create your own template filter to achieve custom actions.